# Finding all pair combinations in strings with several comma separated instances in R

Tags: r

I'm really new to R and trying to solve a, for me, challenging problem.

I have a .csv file containing 22.388 rows with comma separated integers. 
I want to find all possible combinations of pairs of the integers for each row separately and list them pair for pair, so that I'll be able to make a visual representation of them as clusters.

I've tried installing the `combinat` package for R but I can't seem to solve the problem.

An example from my file would be

2 13 
2 8 6

Which should be listed in possible combinations of pairs like this.

2, 13 
2, 8 
2, 6 
8, 6

Comment: Please include a simple example (e.g. two rows and three cols) and expected output.

Comment: You can see how to do a MWE here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @flodel I've included example and expected output in the edited question above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample input - replace `textConnection(...)` with your csv filename.

```
csv <- textConnection("2,13
2,8,6")
```

This reads the input into a list of values:

```
input.lines  <- readLines(csv)
input.values <- strsplit(input.lines, ',')
```

This creates a nested list of pairs:

```
pairs <- lapply(input.values, combn, 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

This puts everything in a nice matrix of integers:

```
pairs.mat <- matrix(as.integer(unlist(pairs)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
pairs.mat
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2   13
# [2,]    2    8
# [3,]    2    6
# [4,]    8    6
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can see where it's going. Only problem now is that my file contains 22.388 rows, and to be specific I have to find all possible combinations of pairs for each line, seperately and not just the entire total combination of pairs. I've edited my question to reflect that more clearly. Can you help - I guess I need to do a loop or something? Thanks!

Comment: @Matias: How is that different from what you already asked for? As an example, see that `13` (line 1 in the file) is not paired with `8` or `6` (line 2 in the file).

Comment: If what you need is a list of two-column matrices, then try: `lapply(pairs, function(x) matrix(as.integer(unlist(x)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

`combn` gives the combinations of the vector elements.  `paste` the combinations together with `apply`:

```
x <- c(2, 13)
y <- c(2, 8, 6)
apply(combn(x, 2), 2, paste, collapse=' ')
[1] "2 13"
```

Loop over these:

```
unlist(sapply(list(x, y), function(x) apply(combn(x, 2), 2, paste, collapse=' ')))
## [1] "2 13" "2 8"  "2 6"  "8 6"
```